# Дана строка, содержащая сумму натуральных чисел. Найдите результат вычислений

Tags: c#

Дана строка, содержащая сумму натуральных чисел. Найдите результат вычислений. Например: `2.5 + 3.5 + 2.5` ответ будет `8.5`. Я сделал набросок программы, но что-то дальше я не очень понимаю что нужно сделать.

Вот код:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string s = "3.5 + 1.5 + 1.5";
    string numbers = "1234567890";
    string x = "";
    isdigit( s,numbers,x);
}

static void isdigit (string s,string numbers,string x)
{         
    s.Split(" ");
    for(int i = 0;i < s.Length; i++)
    { 
        for(int j = 0; j < numbers.Length; j++)
        {
            if(s[i] == numbers[j] && s[i] + 1 =='.' && s[i] + 2 == numbers[j])
            {
                x += s[i];
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Данный пример не подхоит по условию.");
            }
        }
        Console.Write(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ваши числа из примера не являются натуральными числами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Натуральное число](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE).

Если ваши числа сделать натуральными, то получится всё весьма просто, постараюсь без `Linq`, хотя с ним было бы еще проще.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string s = "3 + 2 + 1"; // должно получиться 6
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s + " = " + ComputeSum(s));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Не удалось посчитать сумму, ошибка: " + ex.Message);
    }
}

private static int ComputeSum(string expression)
{
    string[] tokens = expression.Split('+');
    int sum = 0;
    foreach (string token in tokens)
    {
        sum += int.Parse(token);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
3 + 2 + 1 = 6
```

---

Без `try-catch`, при условии что все числа натуральные.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string s = "3 + 2 + 1";
    int sum = ComputeSum(s);
    if (sum >= 0)
        Console.WriteLine(s + " = " + sum);
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Не удалось посчитать сумму");
}

private static int ComputeSum(string expression)
{
    string[] tokens = expression.Split('+');
    int sum = 0;
    foreach (string token in tokens)
    {
        if (int.TryParse(token, out int number))
            sum += number;
        else
            return -1;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: А как можно это сделать без catch/try ? Недавно начал учить string просто

Comment: @Damis без try-catch получится сложнее, вы уверены?

Comment: `.Trim` вроде не нужен: https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYCMBYAUKzATgAoBLKYAOgAUBDMAZwFNiAiAAnc09YEpeA3HgIk4AewgAjADZMa9Zm06ZK3dn0FA===

Comment: @VladD не был до конца уверен, на коленке писал. Спасибо, исправил.

Comment: @aepot: Я тоже не был уверен, поэтому сначала написал в ответе с Trim, потом убрал.

Comment: @aepot Да, уверен. Я учусь по курсам и до catch/try еще не дошел.

Comment: @Damis как скажете, готово.

Comment: @aepot Все идеально, только как можно заменить TryParse ?

Comment: @Damis никак, это единственный способ распарсить целое число без выброса исключения. Ну если вы только не собираетесь написать свой собственный парсер, но какой смысл это делать?

Comment: @aepot Ок, спасибо большое !

Answer (score 3):

Тот же вариант, но с LINQ.

```cs
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
var result = s.Split('+').Sum(double.Parse);
```

И да, ваши числа не натуральные.

Comment: LINQ тоже не учил

Comment: Я сейчас учу методы

Comment: Remove,Substring,IndexOf и тд

Comment: @Damis, "не учил", вы там что, с учебником сидите над каждым методом?) MSDN открыли, описание прочитали и использовали